# How to detect entities automatically with openJPA?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, persistence.xml

I'm looking for an entity detection in OpenJPA. That I don't need to declare all entities in the persistence.xml.

Edit: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I develop a java se app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [Persistent Class List](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_pc_pcclasses) section in the user manual.

> Unlike many ORM products, OpenJPA does
>   not need to know about all of your
>   persistent classes at startup. OpenJPA
>   discovers new persistent classes
>   automatically as they are loaded into
>   the JVM; in fact you can introduce new
>   persistent classes into running
>   applications under OpenJPA.

- Note: There are a couple restrictions that are documented in the user manual but I left those out to keep this post brief.

Answer (score 3):

Per the JPA specification, you must list all classes explicitly in a Java SE environment:

> #### 6.2.1.6 mapping-file, jar-file, class, exclude-unlisted-classes
>
> (...)
>
> A list of named managed persistence
>   classes may also be specified instead
>   of, or in addition to, the JAR files
>   and mapping files. Any mapping
>   metadata annotations found on these
>   classes will be processed, or they
>   will be mapped using the mapping
>   annotation defaults. The class element
>   is used to list a managed persistence
>   class. **A list of all named managed
>   persistence classes must be specified
>   in Java SE environments to insure
>   portability.** Portable Java SE
>   applications should not rely on the
>   other mechanisms described here to
>   specify the managed persistence
>   classes of a persistence unit.
>   Persistence providers may also require
>   that the set of entity classes and
>   classes that are to be managed must be
>   fully enumerated in each of the
>   `persistence.xml` files in Java SE
>   environments.
>
> All classes contained in the root of
>   the persistence unit are also searched
>   for annotated managed persistence
>   classes and any mapping metadata
>   annotations found on them will be
>   processed, or they will be mapped
>   using the mapping annotation defaults.
>   If it is not intended that the
>   annotated persistence classes
>   contained in the root of the
>   persistence unit be included in the
>   persistence unit, the
>   `exclude-unlisted-classes` element
>   should be used. The
>   `exclude-unlisted-classes` element is
>   not intended for use in Java SE
>   environments.

Now, if you don't mind being not portable, you might use a provider extension but I couldn't find something similar to Hibernate's `hibernate.archive.autodetection` property in OpenJPA.

Using Spring's [JPA integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup) (which allows more flexible classpath scanning) is another option.

Comment: It's not applicable to Java SE persistence units. I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I develop a java se app.

Comment: then use spring as suggested in the last paragraph. works in se as well

Comment: @seanizer The comment from the OP precedes my update and the update of the question (my initial suggestion was to set `exclude-unlisted-classes` to `false`).

Answer (score 0):

There is also the JPA-plugin that can do this for you. The latest version is not available in Maven Central so you will have to clone and build yourself.

[JPA-Plugin](https://github.com/ljnelson/jpa-maven-plugin)